# Phone connected to PC but it only charges

Tags: usb-debugging, usb-connection-mode

I'm using windows 10. Connected my phone (Samsung Note 3) to my PC but it only charges. I've done USB Debugging and even installed the driver on my PC. I doubt windows 10 doesn't recognized my phone because I connected to my windows 7 PC but the same thing happened.

Comment: Do you get any notification when you connect. If yes, pull that down and change options to MTP

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no

Comment: I think it is a driver problem. Uninstall them reinstall , reboot and try. That notification comes when the device is recognised by PC. Right now it's only charging because of default USB behaviour. Also go to PC properties and see what it shows for the device connection. If it doesn't show as Samsung certainly it's a driver problem

Comment: I know it might sound stupid, but are you sure that your USB cable is of data-type? There are same looking power-only cables, which obviously allow only charging, and don't have data wires at all. Try with different USB cable as a start.

Comment: :-) Thought so... You're welcome... Happened to few people I know...

Comment: @centier Post the answer yourself and mark this question as solved :)

Answer (score 2):

Not all the USB cables offer data transfer. There are same-looking power-only cables, which obviously allow only charging, and don't have data wires at all.

Try with a different USB cable as a start.

Comment: After this try a Mac if you have one